# How do I restrict access to my network hard drive?

Tags: networking, external-hard-drive, nas

I just bought a [WD My Book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001RB1QWW) NAS for use at home. I want to use it for scheduled backups from my Windows 7 PC(s) as well as general storage. I do not want any remote access. I plugged it into my router and mapped the network drive; now I have 2 questions:

1. I occasionally give visitors my WiFi password (WPA2-PSK) so they can access the internet, but I don't want them to have access to the data on the NAS. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. How can I ensure that my NAS is secure against intruders from outside my home network?

Comment: Do you want to prevent read access, write access, or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) encrypted partition  (or any other disk encryption tool)  on the drive. This would leave you with a encrypted disk that only you can access.

Answer (score 0):

1. It all depends on your router.  Many routers will allow MAC-address-based client permissions, or support partitioning wired vs wireless network.  Check your documentation or poke around in you router control panel.
2. Your router will shield the systems on your network from intruders behind its own firewall and the lack of Network Adress Transmission (NAT) mapped ports.  Just make sure the WD MyBook isn't requesting port mapping via UPnP.  Again, this would be in your router's control panel.